# List as names for names of Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make the names of some stock symbols the actual name of a pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr

choices = ['ROK', 'HWM', 'PYPL', 'V', 'KIM', 'FISV', 'REG', 'EMN', 'GS', 'TYL']

for c in choices:
     pdr.DataReader(c, data_source='yahoo', start=datetime(2000,1,1), 
     end=datetime(2020,1,1)).to_csv(f'Data/{c}.csv')
     f'{c}'['Price'] = pd.read_csv(f'Data/{c}.csv', index_col='Date')['Adj Close']
```

I'm getting this error:
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Is there a way to go about doing this?  Maybe perhaps using the name of the stock symbol as the name of the dataframe is not the best convention.

Thank you

Comment: What is f'{c}'['Price'] supposed to mean? f'{c}' is a string , so that is way you are seeing the error

Answer (score 1):

You can put it in a data structure as a dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr

choices = ['ROK', 'HWM', 'PYPL', 'V', 'KIM', 'FISV', 'REG', 'EMN', 'GS', 'TYL']

dataframes = {}

for c in choices:
     pdr.DataReader(c, data_source='yahoo', start=datetime(2000,1,1), 
     end=datetime(2020,1,1)).to_csv(f'Data/{c}.csv')
     dataframes[c] = pd.read_csv(f'Data/{c}.csv', index_col='Date')['Adj Close']
```

So, you will get a structure like the one bellow:

```
>>> print(dataframes)
{'ROK': <your_ROK_dataframe_here>,
 'HWM': <your_HWM_dataframe_here>,
 ...
}
```

Then, you can access a specific dataframe by using `dataframes['XXXX']` where XXXX is one of the choices.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be storing variables with string as it can get quite messy down the line. If you wanted to keep with your convention I'd advise storing your dataframes as a dictionary with the stock symbols as a key

```
choices = ['ROK', 'HWM', 'PYPL', 'V', 'KIM', 'FISV', 'REG', 'EMN', 'GS', 'TYL']
choices_dict = {}
for c in choices:
     pdr.DataReader(c, data_source='yahoo', start=datetime(2000,1,1), 
     end=datetime(2020,1,1)).to_csv(f'Data/{c}.csv')
     csv_pd = pd.read_csv(f'Data/{c}.csv', index_col='Date')['Adj Close']
     choices_dict[c] = pd.DataFrame(csv_pd, columns=['Price'])
```